# DELPHI Equivalent of a Visual Basic 6 Function

Tags: function, delphi, math

I would like an equivalent function in Delphi for the following function which is written in Visual Basic 6:

```vb
Public Function ToString(ByVal l As Long, n As Integer) As String    
  ' Convert a long value to a string, left padded with chr$(0)    
  Dim s As String
  Dim i As Integer
  s = ""
  Do While l > 0
    i = l Mod 256
    s = Chr$(i) & s
    l = CLng((l - i) / 256)
  Loop        
  ToString = Right$(String$(n, Chr$(0)) & s, n)        
End Function
```

I tried in the following way, but no success:

```pascal
function ToString(l: Longint; n: Smallint): String;
var
  s: String;
  i: Smallint;
begin
  s := '';
  while l > 0 do
  begin
    i := l mod 256;
    s := String(Char(i))+s;
    l := Round((l-i)/256);
  end;
  Result := (StringOfChar(String(Char(0))[1], n)+s, n);
end;
```

Comment: inttostr : is straight forward but how about the calculations.I am an intermediate Delphi learner :(

Comment: Thank Ken for getting back to me :   Function ToString(1: Integer, n : Integer) : String ;

  var
  S:string;
   i: Integer
Begin
  s := ''  ;

End ;

Comment: function ToString(l: Longint; n: Smallint): String;
var
 s: String;
 i: Smallint;
begin

 s := '';
 while l>0 do
  begin
  i := l mod 256;
  s := String(Char(i))+s;
  l := Round((l-i)/256);
 end;
 Result := (StringOfChar(String(Char(0))[1], n)+s, n);

end;

Comment: There is no need to translate the VB code to Delphi, just use [`SysUtils.Format()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format), eg: `function ToString(l: Longint; n: Smallint): String; var fmt: string; begin fmt := Format('%%.%dd', [n]); Result := Format(fmt, [l]); end;`  Alternatively, use [`SysUtils.IntToStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.IntToStr), eg: `function ToString(l: Longint; n: Smallint): String; begin Result := IntToStr(l); if Length(Result) < n then Result := StringOfChar('0', n - Length(Result)) + Result; end;`

Comment: Thanks Remy but it is not functioning: '99999999' as String should convert to õàÿ

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you also add (with an [edit] to the question) sample input and output for the VB version? Several sample inputs and the output for each of them would help.

Comment: You VB function create a string but not a string representing a number in the usual decimal format. Indeed Chr$(i) do NOT return the ascii code for a digit. It even produce control characters. Is it really what you want? As Ken white told you, please edit your question and add several sample inputs and corresponding output for you VB code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming a UNICODE capable Delphi)

You are using a STRING to store binary values - don't do that. Strings are for textual representation - not for binary storage. Use a byte array (TBytes) instead.

If you MUST (but you don't) you should use RawByteString instead, as

1. It is a single-byte-per-character string (as opposed to UNICODE STRING's 2-bytes-per-character)
2. It does not contain any implicit code page so no conversion is performed on assignment back and forth.

You can use this function:

```
FUNCTION IntToBin(Value : LongWord ; CONST Len : BYTE) : RawByteString;
  VAR
    I   : INTEGER;

  BEGIN
    SetLength(Result,Len);
    FillChar(Result[LOW(Result)],Len,0);
    I:=HIGH(Result);
    WHILE (I>=LOW(Result)) AND (Value<>0) DO BEGIN
      Result[I]:=AnsiChar(Value MOD 256);
      Value:=Value DIV 256;
      DEC(I)
    END
  END;
```

Comment: Many Thanks HearWare for your big Help. I got your Points described above. Have a great Day !